# How can I make sure I have successfully disabled SSL 2.0

Tags: tls, openssl

I followed some websites that were pointing me to Registry keys to enable or disable . I wanted to enabled TLS 1.2 and disable SSL . ( For local testing purposes ).
But now how can I make sure this has worked correctly?